# FreeBSD - 'cd ~' takes me to /root instead of home directory

Tags: freebsd, home-directory

I just created a new user (I was logged in as root to do so) with the adduser utility. I gave the new user his own home directory. If I check the /etc/passwd file, it shows the users home folder is correct and even when I ssh into the server as that user it starts me off in the correct folder. However, whenever I type "cd ~", it takes me to /root. Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things to check:

- If you `sudo` to the new user using `sudo -u <newuser>`, make sure you pass the `-H` flag, so that it will set the HOME environment variable, like so: `sudo -u <newuser> -H`.
- If you use `su`, make sure you use `su -` so that it will launch a login shell, which will explicitly set your HOME variable.
- If you are logging in as this user from the get-go, you can verify that your home directory is set correctly in *sh by using `echo $HOME` to verify which HOME directory *sh THINKS you're using.

Hope these tips (and their explanations) help!

Comment: I was SSHing directly to the new user account. When the connection was made, It put me into the users home folder, but if I then typed "cd ~", it took me to /root.

As for the other responses below, I wasn't su'ing into the user, I was logging in as the new user himself. I didn't check the uid of the user.. I didn't think two users could have the same uid?

At any rate, our plans changed and I don't need this new user anymore, so it's been deleted. Thanks for all the suggestions though!

Answer (score 0):

Did you log in as the user or did you `su` to the new user?  If you used `su`, did you use `su -` or whatever the BSD equivalent is to make sure you use th new user's environment?

Answer (score 0):

it's because youe euid is root. So you've done su or sudo to have root rights

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, you did assign this user his own uid, and he's not using the same uid as root?